# springdoc-openapi-gradle-plugin hook generating doc after build task in Gradle

Tags: gradle, springdoc

I would like to have openapi file generated during build time.

When I configure `generateOpenApiDocs` to be run after `build`:

```kotlin
tasks.named("build") {
    finalizedBy("generateOpenApiDocs")
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':forkedSpringBootRun' (type 'JavaExecFork').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/user/projects/service/build/classes/java/aot'.
    
    Reason: Task ':forkedSpringBootRun' uses this output of task ':compileAotJava' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
```

I tried `forkedSpringBootRun`/`doNotTrackState` but it does not work for me - I still get the error mentioned before.

Repository with reproduction - https://github.com/kkocel/openapigradlerepro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

Additionally configure `forkedSpringBootRun` in your build script:

```kotlin
tasks {
  forkedSpringBootRun {
    doNotTrackState("See https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-gradle-plugin/issues/102")
  }
}
```

If after that Gradle build still fails with the same message you have to define in `forkedSpringBootRun` all the first level dependent tasks in `dependsOn()`, e.g.:

```kotlin
tasks {
    forkedSpringBootRun {
        dependsOn(
            project.tasks.named("distTar"),
            project.tasks.named("test"),
            ..
        )
    }
}
```

**Known Issue**

The project itself still has open issue regarding issue with the task accessing files from output of another task not having a direct dependency on it.

Issue reported in the project: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-gradle-plugin/issues/128

Consequences

Remember this is only a workaround until plugin properly declared task dependencies. As a result this task won't be optimized and can slightly impact your build performance. Read more about [untracked tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/UntrackedTask.html).